# I can't adapt my dataset to VGG-net, getting size mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, vgg-net, transfer-learning

I’m trying to implement the pre-trained VGG net to my script, in order to recognize faces from my dataset in RGB [256,256], but I’m getting a “size mismatch, m1: [1 x 2622], m2: [4096 x 2]” even if i'm resizing my images it doesn't work, as you can see my code work with resnet and alexnet.

I've tryed resizing the images with the function interpolate but the size mismatch persist.

```
def training(model_conv, learning_rate, wd, net):

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight= torch.FloatTensor([1,1]))
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model_conv.fc.parameters(),         lr=learning_rate, weight_decay = wd)
total_step = len(train_loader)
loss_list = []
acc_list = []
print("Inizio il training")

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (im, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):  

        images = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(im, 224, mode = 'bilinear')
        outputs = model_conv(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss_list.append(loss.item())
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if (i + 1) % 100 == 0:
            print('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'
                  .format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, i + 1, total_step, loss.item()))
torch.save(model_conv, 'TrainedModel.pt')
return images, labels

def main():

net = "vgg"
learning_rate = 10e-6
wd = 10e-4

if net == "vgg":
    print("Hai selezionato VGG")
    model_conv = VGG_FACE.vgg_face
    data = torch.load("VGG_FACE.pth")
    model_conv.load_state_dict(data) 

    model_conv.fc = nn.Linear(4096, 2)
    model_conv[-1] = model_conv.fc

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

For example this is another code where I used correctly my VGG with some random images

```
def test():
N=5
net = VGG_FACE.vgg_face
data = torch.load("VGG_FACE.pth")
net.load_state_dict(data)
net.eval()
names = open("names.txt").read().split()

with torch.no_grad():
    mean = np.array([93.5940, 104.7624, 129.1863])
    images = scipy.misc.imread("cooper2.jpg", mode="RGB")
    images = scipy.misc.imresize(images, [224, 224])
    images = images.astype(np.float32)
    images -= mean[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
    images = np.transpose(images, (2, 0, 1))
    images = images[np.newaxis, ...]
    images = torch.tensor(images, dtype=torch.float32)


    y = net(images)
    y = torch.nn.functional.softmax(y, 1)
    rank = torch.topk(y[0, :], N)
    for i in range(N):
        index = rank[1][i].item()
        score = rank[0][i].item()
        print("{}) {} ({:.2f})".format(i + 1, names[index], score))
    print()


numero_classi = 2
net[-1] = torch.nn.Linear(4096, numero_classi)


if __name__ == "__main__":
test()
```

the error i'm gettin is

```
  File "/Users/danieleligato/PycharmProjects/parametral/VGGTEST.py", line 53, in training
outputs = model_conv(images)
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [4 x 2622], m2: [4096 x 2] at /Users/soumith/code/builder/wheel/pytorch-src/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:2070
```

**THIS IS THE VGG NET THAT I'M USING**

```
class LambdaBase(nn.Sequential):
def __init__(self, fn, *args):
    super(LambdaBase, self).__init__(*args)
    self.lambda_func = fn

def forward_prepare(self, input):
    output = []
    for module in self._modules.values():
        output.append(module(input))
    return output if output else input

class Lambda(LambdaBase):
def forward(self, input):
    return self.lambda_func(self.forward_prepare(input))

class LambdaMap(LambdaBase):
def forward(self, input):
    return map(self.lambda_func,self.forward_prepare(input))

class LambdaReduce(LambdaBase):
def forward(self, input):
    return reduce(self.lambda_func,self.forward_prepare(input))


vgg_face = nn.Sequential( # Sequential,
nn.Conv2d(3,64,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(64,64,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2),(2, 2),(0, 0),ceil_mode=True),
nn.Conv2d(64,128,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(128,128,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2),(2, 2),(0, 0),ceil_mode=True),
nn.Conv2d(128,256,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(256,256,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(256,256,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2),(2, 2),(0, 0),ceil_mode=True),
nn.Conv2d(256,512,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(512,512,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(512,512,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2),(2, 2),(0, 0),ceil_mode=True),
nn.Conv2d(512,512,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(512,512,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(512,512,(3, 3),(1, 1),(1, 1)),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2),(2, 2),(0, 0),ceil_mode=True),
Lambda(lambda x: x.view(x.size(0),-1)), # View,
nn.Sequential(Lambda(lambda x: x.view(1,-1) if 1==len(x.size()) else x ),nn.Linear(25088,4096)), # Linear,
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Dropout(0.5),
nn.Sequential(Lambda(lambda x: x.view(1,-1) if 1==len(x.size()) else x ),nn.Linear(4096,4096)), # Linear,
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Dropout(0.5),
nn.Sequential(Lambda(lambda x: x.view(1,-1) if 1==len(x.size()) else x ),nn.Linear(4096,2622)), # Linear,
)
```

Comment: This is impossible for us to debug. Post a minimum example (reduce the code as small as possible to describe the problem) and paste the exact line and full error description

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, now is much simpler.
Hope maybe you can help me

Comment: Pytorch error returns a line number. which line is giving the size mismatch error?

Comment: The line where I give the tensor to my net.
Here   **outputs = model_conv(images)**

Comment: Ok, what is the code for model_conv?

Comment: model_conv is my **vgg-net**, infact in the code i did
_model_conv = VGG_FACE.vgg_face_
You can find the code of the vgg_net in the post, I've just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
model_conv.fc = nn.Linear(4096, 2)
```

Change to:

```
model_conv.fc = nn.Linear(2622, 2)
```